Group isomorphism which preserves cycle structure
Let $G$, $H$ be subgroups of symmetric group $S_n$.
Let $\phi \colon G \to H$ be a group isomorphism such that for each $g \in G$ elements $g$ and $\phi(g)$ have the same cycle structure. In that case for each $g \in G$ elements $g$ and $\phi(g)$ are conjugated, i.e. $\forall g\in G$ $\exists f = f(g)\in S_n$: $g = f^{-1}\phi(g)f$ (there is dependence $f \in S_n$ on $g$).
Question: does there exist an element $t\in S_n$ such that $\phi(g) = t^{-1}gt$ for each $g\in G$?

Just to clarify: your $t$ shall not depend on $g$? You ask if $\phi = t^{-1} Id_G t$?

@TimonKolt, $t$ shall not depend on $g$.

To answer your attempt at an edited question, which you should make as a separate post, any two isomorphic subgroups of $S_n$ where all elements fix 0 or 1 point are conjugate. This is because $G$ and $H$ are Frobenius groups in this case, with Frobenius complements of the same order, hence conjugate inside $G$ by Schur-Zassenhaus.

Such an element $t$ does not exist in general.
As a counterexample consider the following two copies of the Klein four-group in $\mathrm{S}_6$: $G = \langle (1\;2)(3\;4), (1\;3)(2\;4)\rangle$ and $H = \langle (1\;2)(3\;4), (1\;2)(5\;6)\rangle$. Both contain the identity and three double transpositions, so every isomorphism $G \to H$ preserves the cycle structures. However, the two subgroups are not conjugate. This can be seen easiest by noting that $5$ and $6$ are fixed by the action of $G$. The action of $H$ does not have any fixed points.

I'm studing permutation groups such that every $g \in G\setminus {1}$ has $1$ or $0$ fixed points. May be this condition helps to proof that $\phi$ is conjugation? Or there is a class of groups for which these proposition is true?

The question was edited.

Please don't make such important changes to the question after an answer has been posted. Now we have an answer that is relevant to a question that can only be seen in the edit history.
